# How do I get all possible paths in terms of edges, and not vertices in Mathematica?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have an undirected graph

```
G = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 4}, 
     EdgeLabels -> {1 <-> 2 -> A, 2 <-> 3 -> B, 2 <-> 4 -> C, 3 <-> 4 -> D}]
```

[image]

I used `FindPath[G, 1, 4, Infinity, All]` and got the result as

> `{{1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}`

Although this result is true, I want this result to display possible paths in terms of edges, and not vertices. For above example, I want the result to be

> `{{A, C}, {A, B, D}}`

Is there any way to do this? Actually, I have a large graph with **107** possible paths from source node to destination node, and I want to identify those paths with respect to edges.

**Application as suggested in comment:**

```
el = {1 <-> 2 -> a, 2 <-> 3 -> b, 3 <-> 4 -> c, 4 <-> 5 -> d, 
  2 <-> 6 -> e, 4 <-> 6 -> f, 5 <-> 7 -> g, 6 <-> 7 -> h, 
  2 <-> 8 -> i, 6 <-> 9 -> j, 7 <-> 10 -> k, 8 <-> 9 -> l, 
  8 <-> 11 -> m, 9 <-> 10 -> n, 9 <-> 12 -> o, 10 <-> 13 -> p, 
  11 <-> 12 -> q, 11 <-> 14 -> r, 11 <-> 15 -> s, 12 <-> 13 -> t, 
  13 <-> 14 -> u, 14 <-> 15 -> v}
UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ {{1, 2, 8, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 
    8, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 9, 12, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 9, 12, 11, 
    15}, {1, 2, 6, 9, 8, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 
    2, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 9, 12, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 
    9, 10, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 9, 12,
     11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 9, 8, 11, 
    14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 7, 10, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 
    11, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 13, 
    12, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 9, 12, 13, 14, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 9, 10, 
    13, 14, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 9, 10, 13, 12, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 7, 
    10, 13, 14, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 7, 10, 13, 12, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 
    7, 10, 9, 12, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 
    4, 6, 9, 12, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 8, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 11,
     12, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 13, 12, 11, 14, 15}, {1,
     2, 8, 9, 6, 7, 10, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 9, 10, 13, 12, 11, 14, 
    15}, {1, 2, 6, 9, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 7, 10, 13, 12,
     11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 7, 10, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 7, 
    10, 9, 12, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2,
     6, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 13, 14, 
    15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 
    13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 8, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7,
     10, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 9,
     6, 7, 10, 13, 14, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 9, 6, 7, 10, 13, 12, 11, 
    15}, {1, 2, 6, 7, 10, 13, 12, 9, 8, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 7, 10, 9, 
    12, 13, 14, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13, 14, 11, 15}, {1, 
    2, 6, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13, 12, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 12, 
    11, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 
    12, 13, 14, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 11, 15}, {1, 
    2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 13, 12, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 13, 14,
     11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 13, 12, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 
    7, 10, 9, 12, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 11, 15}, {1, 
    2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13, 14, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13, 12,
     11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 12, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
    7, 10, 9, 8, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 9, 12, 11, 15}, {1, 2,
     3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 9, 8, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 11, 12, 9, 6, 7, 10, 13, 
    14, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 9, 6, 7, 10, 13, 12, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 9, 
    6, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 7, 10, 13, 12, 9, 8, 11, 
    14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 4, 
    5, 7, 10, 13, 12, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 12, 13, 
    14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 12, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 4, 
    5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 13, 12, 11, 
    14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 
    6, 7, 10, 13, 12, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 9, 12, 13, 
    14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 9, 12, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 
    6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13, 12, 11, 
    14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 7, 10, 9, 12, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 11, 14,
     15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7,
     6, 9, 12, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 
    15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 9, 8, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 9, 6, 4, 
    5, 7, 10, 13, 14, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 9, 6, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13, 12, 
    11, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13, 12, 9, 8, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 
    4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 12, 13, 14, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 13, 
    12, 9, 8, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 9, 12, 13, 14, 11, 
    15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13, 12, 9, 8, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
     7, 10, 9, 12, 13, 14, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 9, 12, 13, 
    14, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 
    3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 9, 10, 13, 12, 11, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 11, 12, 9, 6, 4, 
    5, 7, 10, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 8, 9, 6, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13, 12, 11, 
    14, 15}, {1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13, 12, 9, 8, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 
    6, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 
    13, 12, 9, 8, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8, 11, 12, 
    13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13, 12, 9, 8, 11, 14, 15}, {1,
     2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 
    6, 9, 10, 13, 12, 11, 14, 15}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 9, 8, 11, 12,
     13, 14, 15}} /. el
```

For the above code, I got the result

> ```
> {{a, i, m, s}, {a, i, m, r, v}, {a, i, l, o, 12 <-> 11, s}, {a, e, j, 
>   o, 12 <-> 11, s}, {a, e, j, 9 <-> 8, m, s}, {a, i, m, q, t, u, 
>   v}, {a, i, l, o, t, u, v}, {a, i, l, o, 12 <-> 11, r, v}, {a, i, l, 
>   n, p, u, v}, {a, e, j, o, t, u, v}, {a, e, j, o, 12 <-> 11, r, 
>   v}, {a, e, j, n, p, u, v}, {a, e, j, 9 <-> 8, m, r, v}, {a, e, h, k,
>    p, u, v}, {a, i, l, o, t, u, 14 <-> 11, s}, {a, i, l, n, p, u, 
>   14 <-> 11, s}, {a, i, l, n, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, s}, {a, e, j, 
>   o, t, u, 14 <-> 11, s}, {a, e, j, n, p, u, 14 <-> 11, s}, {a, e, j, 
>   n, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, s}, {a, e, h, k, p, u, 14 <-> 11, 
>   s}, {a, e, h, k, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, s}, {a, e, h, k, 10 <-> 9,
>    o, 12 <-> 11, s}, {a, e, h, k, 10 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, m, s}, {a, b, c, 
>   f, j, o, 12 <-> 11, s}, {a, b, c, f, j, 9 <-> 8, m, s}, {a, i, m, q,
>    12 <-> 9, n, p, u, v}, {a, i, l, n, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, r, 
>   v}, {a, i, l, 9 <-> 6, h, k, p, u, v}, {a, e, j, n, p, 13 <-> 12, 
>   12 <-> 11, r, v}, {a, e, j, 9 <-> 8, m, q, t, u, v}, {a, e, h, k, p,
>    13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, r, v}, {a, e, h, k, 10 <-> 9, o, t, u, 
>   v}, {a, e, h, k, 10 <-> 9, o, 12 <-> 11, r, v}, {a, e, h, k, 
>   10 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, m, r, v}, {a, e, 6 <-> 4, d, g, k, p, u, v}, {a, 
>   b, c, f, j, o, t, u, v}, {a, b, c, f, j, o, 12 <-> 11, r, v}, {a, b,
>    c, f, j, n, p, u, v}, {a, b, c, f, j, 9 <-> 8, m, r, v}, {a, b, c, 
>   f, h, k, p, u, v}, {a, b, c, d, g, k, p, u, v}, {a, i, l, 9 <-> 6, 
>   h, k, p, u, 14 <-> 11, s}, {a, i, l, 9 <-> 6, h, k, p, 13 <-> 12, 
>   12 <-> 11, s}, {a, e, h, k, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, m, 
>   s}, {a, e, h, k, 10 <-> 9, o, t, u, 14 <-> 11, s}, {a, e, 6 <-> 4, 
>   d, g, k, p, u, 14 <-> 11, s}, {a, e, 6 <-> 4, d, g, k, p, 13 <-> 12,
>    12 <-> 11, s}, {a, e, 6 <-> 4, d, g, k, 10 <-> 9, o, 12 <-> 11, 
>   s}, {a, e, 6 <-> 4, d, g, k, 10 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, m, s}, {a, b, c, f, 
>   j, o, t, u, 14 <-> 11, s}, {a, b, c, f, j, n, p, u, 14 <-> 11, 
>   s}, {a, b, c, f, j, n, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, s}, {a, b, c, f, h, 
>   k, p, u, 14 <-> 11, s}, {a, b, c, f, h, k, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, 
>   s}, {a, b, c, f, h, k, 10 <-> 9, o, 12 <-> 11, s}, {a, b, c, f, h, 
>   k, 10 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, m, s}, {a, b, c, d, g, k, p, u, 14 <-> 11, 
>   s}, {a, b, c, d, g, k, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, s}, {a, b, c, d, g, 
>   k, 10 <-> 9, o, 12 <-> 11, s}, {a, b, c, d, g, k, 10 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8,
>    m, s}, {a, b, c, d, g, 7 <-> 6, j, o, 12 <-> 11, s}, {a, b, c, d, 
>   g, 7 <-> 6, j, 9 <-> 8, m, s}, {a, i, m, q, 12 <-> 9, 9 <-> 6, h, k,
>    p, u, v}, {a, i, l, 9 <-> 6, h, k, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, r, 
>   v}, {a, i, l, 9 <-> 6, 6 <-> 4, d, g, k, p, u, v}, {a, e, h, k, p, 
>   13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, m, r, v}, {a, e, h, k, 10 <-> 9, 
>   9 <-> 8, m, q, t, u, v}, {a, e, 6 <-> 4, d, g, k, p, 13 <-> 12, 
>   12 <-> 11, r, v}, {a, e, 6 <-> 4, d, g, k, 10 <-> 9, o, t, u, 
>   v}, {a, e, 6 <-> 4, d, g, k, 10 <-> 9, o, 12 <-> 11, r, v}, {a, e, 
>   6 <-> 4, d, g, k, 10 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, m, r, v}, {a, b, c, f, j, n, p,
>    13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, r, v}, {a, b, c, f, j, 9 <-> 8, m, q, t, u, 
>   v}, {a, b, c, f, h, k, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, r, v}, {a, b, c, f, 
>   h, k, 10 <-> 9, o, t, u, v}, {a, b, c, f, h, k, 10 <-> 9, o, 
>   12 <-> 11, r, v}, {a, b, c, f, h, k, 10 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, m, r, 
>   v}, {a, b, c, d, g, k, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, r, v}, {a, b, c, d, 
>   g, k, 10 <-> 9, o, t, u, v}, {a, b, c, d, g, k, 10 <-> 9, o, 
>   12 <-> 11, r, v}, {a, b, c, d, g, k, 10 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, m, r, 
>   v}, {a, b, c, d, g, 7 <-> 6, j, o, t, u, v}, {a, b, c, d, g, 
>   7 <-> 6, j, o, 12 <-> 11, r, v}, {a, b, c, d, g, 7 <-> 6, j, n, p, 
>   u, v}, {a, b, c, d, g, 7 <-> 6, j, 9 <-> 8, m, r, v}, {a, i, l, 
>   9 <-> 6, 6 <-> 4, d, g, k, p, u, 14 <-> 11, s}, {a, i, l, 9 <-> 6, 
>   6 <-> 4, d, g, k, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, s}, {a, e, 6 <-> 4, d, g,
>    k, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, m, s}, {a, e, 6 <-> 4, d, g, k,
>    10 <-> 9, o, t, u, 14 <-> 11, s}, {a, b, c, f, h, k, p, 13 <-> 12, 
>   12 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, m, s}, {a, b, c, f, h, k, 10 <-> 9, o, t, u, 
>   14 <-> 11, s}, {a, b, c, d, g, k, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, 
>   m, s}, {a, b, c, d, g, k, 10 <-> 9, o, t, u, 14 <-> 11, s}, {a, b, 
>   c, d, g, 7 <-> 6, j, o, t, u, 14 <-> 11, s}, {a, b, c, d, g, 
>   7 <-> 6, j, n, p, u, 14 <-> 11, s}, {a, b, c, d, g, 7 <-> 6, j, n, 
>   p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, s}, {a, i, m, q, 12 <-> 9, 9 <-> 6, 
>   6 <-> 4, d, g, k, p, u, v}, {a, i, l, 9 <-> 6, 6 <-> 4, d, g, k, p, 
>   13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, r, v}, {a, e, 6 <-> 4, d, g, k, p, 13 <-> 12, 
>   12 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, m, r, v}, {a, e, 6 <-> 4, d, g, k, 10 <-> 9, 
>   9 <-> 8, m, q, t, u, v}, {a, b, c, f, h, k, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 9, 
>   9 <-> 8, m, r, v}, {a, b, c, f, h, k, 10 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, m, q, t, u,
>    v}, {a, b, c, d, g, k, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, m, r, 
>   v}, {a, b, c, d, g, k, 10 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, m, q, t, u, v}, {a, b, c, 
>   d, g, 7 <-> 6, j, n, p, 13 <-> 12, 12 <-> 11, r, v}, {a, b, c, d, g,
>    7 <-> 6, j, 9 <-> 8, m, q, t, u, v}}
> ```

Comment: Put the edge labels specification in a symbol, e.g. *el*. Then, `UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ vl/. el` where *vl* is the list of vertices lists. BTW - avoid using uppercase initials for your symbols, might clash with a built-in.

Comment: @ciao.. I applied the code as you said. But I am getting combination of vertices and edges as paths. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't know - works for me. Might you post a (short) example of input where it fails?

Comment: @Ciao.. I have edited the description to indicate result. Have a look what I got.

Comment: Change the `el` in the statement to `Join[el, MapAt[Reverse, el, {All, 1}]]`... give that a whirl (it was missing edges where vertex order is reversed).

Comment: @Ciao.. It works perfectly.

Comment: Note that edges are represented as vertex pairs in Mathematica.  Are you sure that you want the *edge labels* (which are only for display) and not the actual edges?  Edge labels are good for display, but you will not be able to use them for any programming/data-processing task with Mathematica graph.

Comment: @Szabolcs.. I want the actual edges. My next step would be to create a zero-one matrix out of all possible paths.